# Azure Media Services Status Disconnected

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I move one AMS (Azure Media Service) and their Storage Account to another subscription at Azure Portal Tool. The migration was complete sucessfully. But before the migration the AMS was Active and now is is Disconnected.

Why? How can turn Active again ?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this, I ran into this problem after moving my storage account to a different resource group. This was the same primary storage account as my Azure Media Service was using. When I checked the Media Service in the Azure Portal, the state was listed as Disconnected.

In order to resolve it, I went to https://resources.azure.com/ to update the URI of the underlying storage account for the Media Service.

In Azure Resource explorer, navigate to: `resourceGroups/<Resource Group name>/providers/Microsoft.Media/mediaservices/<media service name>`

In your Media Service definition, find the following key:

```
"storageAccounts": [
      {
        "id": "/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION NUMBER>/resourceGroups/<**Old** Resource Group name>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<Storage Account name>",
        "type": "Primary"
      }
```

And update it to point to the new storage account URI, which you can get simply by navigating to the storage account in the Azure Portal and looking at the browser's address bar. Then once you replace it with the new address, just click **Patch** to save the change.

Answer (score 0):

The portal shows Disconnected when the Storage attached to the AMS is new (not the classic). So this is by design and you can manage your AMS account from the new portal.